# How to select tags containing no some elements in nested tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is the html code:

```
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>...</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>D</td>
                    <td>...</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="click">click</button>
</body>
```

What I want is get the text `A` and `C` in the above html code. In fact, I have tried some methods. My thought is to select `td` tag elements which do not have the descent tag element of `table`. However, I only can get these `td` elements with descent tag element of `table`, the jquery code is following. 
You can try to run on [`jsddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/zCvTT/6/).

```
$("#click").on("click", function () {
var ss = $("td:has(table)");
$.each(ss, function (index, value) {
        alert(index + $(this).html());
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#click").on("click", function () {
    $("td").each(function(index){
        if(($(this).closest('table').parent('td').length == 0) && ($(this).find('table').length == 0))
           alert(index + $(this).html());
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zCvTT/8/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer in advance, but the two methods do not get what I want, the text `A` and `C`. You may try them in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zCvTT/6/).

Answer (score 0):

> My thought is to select td tag elements which **do not have** the descent tag element of table.

Then use [not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$("#click").on("click", function () {
var ss = $("td:not(:has(table))");
$.each(ss, function (index, value) {
        alert(index + $(this).html());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I have tried this method, but not get what I want. I only walk to the place getting `td` containing the descent tag of `table`. You can try [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zCvTT/6/) to edit and run online.

Comment: yes, I want to get only the text `A` and `C` not all texts in `td`. You can try [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zCvTT/8/), which only show `A` and `C`.

Answer (score 0):

I also find another solution to the question, which may be more easily understood for a newbie as me. Though the html part does not show tag `tbody`, it exists indeed. I checked and displayed the body of `table`. Then to select the first `td` of each `tr` in the first `table`. The javascript code is following.

```
$("#click").on("click", function () {
  $("#message").text($("table").html());
  var trs = $("tbody:first > tr");
  $.each(trs, function (index, value) {
    var td = $(this).find("td:first");
    alert(td.text());
  });
});
```